# Split string by whitespace in Rails unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to split a string by whitespace

```
irb(main):001:0> input = "dog cat"
=> "dog cat"
irb(main):002:0> output = input.strip.split(/\s+/)
=> ["dog", "cat"]
```

This is good. However, I'm also doing this in the controller in Rails, and when I supply the same input, and have it print out the output `#{output}` into my view, it shows as `dogcat` instead of `["dog", "cat"]`. I am really confused how that can happen. Any ideas?

I'm printing it using `@notice = "#{output}"` in the controller, and in my view I have `<%= @notice %>`

Comment: How are you printing it in your view? Could you show the code for that?

Comment: When you use split you end up with an array. You may want to try iterating over your array instead of just printing it. What is the output in view that you ultimately want?

Comment: By default, [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split) will break on white space so `/\s+/` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than splitting your string in the controller and sending it as an array to your view, send the entire string to your view:

```
input = "dog cat"
@notice = input
```

Then, in your view, split your the string and display it as a stringified-array:

```
<%= array(@notice.strip.split(/\s+/)).to_s %>
```

Comment: `#{}` is for interpolating in double quoted strings. It doesn't have anything to do with views or controllers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're correct regarding interpolation within double quotes... I had not realized that it is agnostic to location within the MVC. Updated to reflect.

Comment: You're welcome. I was wondering about the `array` method that you're using. Is that a view helper? I can't find the documentation for it. Just curious...

Answer (score 0):

If you print an array of strings, you'll get the strings all concatenated together. You'd get the same thing in `irb` if you had entered, `print "#{output}"`. You need to decide how you want to format them and print them that way, perhaps with a simple helper function. For example, the helper could do:

```
output.each { |s| puts "<p>#{s}</p>" }
```

Or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your example code:

```
>> input = "dog cat"
=> "dog cat"
>> output = input.strip.split /\s+/
=> ["dog", "cat"]
>> joined = output.join ' '
=> "dog cat"
```

Remember too that Ruby has several helpers like `%w` and `%W` for letting you convert a string into an array of words. If you're starting with an array of words, each of which may have whitespace before and after its individual item, you might try something like this:

```
>> # `input` is an array of words that was populated Somewhere Else
>> # `input` has the initial value ["  dog ", "cat\n", "\r tribble\t"]
>> output = input.join.split /\s+/
=> ["dog", "cat", "tribble"]
>> joined = output.join ' '
=> "dog cat tribble"
```

Calling `String#join` without any parameter will join stringish array items together with *no* separation between them, and is what seems to be done in your example where you just render the array as a string

```
>> @notice = output
>> # @notice will render as 'dogcat'
```

As opposed to:

```
>> @notice = input.join.split(/\s+/).join ' '
>> # @notice will render as 'dog cat'
```

And there you go.